# simple single HTTP response using netcat as web server on macOS

Tags: http, curl, webserver, netcat

I'm using macOS and have netcat installed via Homebrew

```
$ brew info netcat
netcat: stable 0.7.1 (bottled)
Utility for managing network connections
http://netcat.sourceforge.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/netcat/0.7.1 (11 files, 104.2K) *
  Poured from bottle on 2016-06-21 at 12:19:18
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/netcat.rb
```

I'm just trying to get netcat to respond to an incoming curl request, but I think the problem I'm having is that netcat doesn't know *when* to respond.

Here is the content expected to be sent back, it's stored in `response.txt`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Here is the netcat command being run in one terminal shell:

```
sudo nc -l -p 80 < response.txt
```

Here is the curl command being run in another terminal shell:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:80
```

Could someone help me understand what I would need to do in order to get this working as intended.

I can get this to work by using netcat instead of curl for the connection, but ideally I'd like a non-netcat client (such as curl or a web browser) to make a connection to localhost:80 and have the first instance of netcat respond.

Thanks.

Comment: In `nc` you cannot use the `-p` flag together with the `-l` flag. That does not make sense and will throw an error. This is clearly explained in the man pages.

Comment: Using this instead works without issue for me: `sudo nc -l 80 < response.txt`. The `curl` command receives and outputs the text stored in the file `response.txt`

Comment: @arkascha thanks for the reply, I see now you're quite correct with regards to the use of -p not making any sense, but trying `sudo nc -l 80 < response.txt` in one shell and `curl -v 127.0.0.1:80` in another doesn't work for me. I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: The same works without issue for me, I just tried again just to be certain. There must be some other issue on your side. Maybe a local firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the macOS netcat instead of homebrew, and drop the -p option:

```
sudo /usr/bin/nc -l 80 < response.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between gnu's version and macOS' though (with regards to this particular example)? But hey, it worked. Thanks :-)

Comment: Note that `nc` will send the response as soon as the connection is established, which won't always be before the client sends the HTTP GET request. For many clients like Chrome and Firefox this doesn't seem to be an issue, but for at least Safari this is treated as an error and no request gets made

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind to include the full request details (Response, Headers, etc..) in "response.txt"